# Identity column in a budget table

Tags: sql-server, identity-column

Programming noob here, and DBA I am not..

I am creating a table called 'budget' on a 2005 sqlserver databases.  The purpose of this table is to simply store the monthly $ allowed to departments for budgeting purposes.

The essential columns in this table will be month, year, dept, amount.  I am migrating this from an old foxpro table which did not have an identity/primary key column.

My question is, for my purposes do I need to worry about creating an identity column?  I am having a hard time importing the data into SQLserver and having it populate the ID column, so I am inclined to just skip it if it's not needed.  Thanks for your $.02

Comment: Can you define `I am having a hard time importing the data into SQLserver`

Comment: You don't need to have one, its just a good idea to have one. but having one for the sake of having one isn't always a good idea... so in conclusion definitely maybe! On a serious note, I would put one in, possibly `BudgetID` as its something that the values belong to, not sure about the date being split over two columns, I'd just have one. If its set as an `identity` column in your table definition you wont need to set it when you are inserting into the table

Comment: My impression is that SQLserver should handle populating the identity column automatically.  When I tried importing from a sql query utility (aqua data studio), I get an error message for each transaction: "Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'budget' either when identity _insert is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column"

Comment: yes SQL server handles the identity columns automatic. But that also means that when you write an insert command, you are not allowed to use the identity field there. Leave it out from your insert statement and it will work

Comment: Thanks all.  @dbajtr, I created a datetime column to supplement the legacy year & month columns that are used in legacy apps.  At some point, I'll drop them.   I changed: "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.BUDGET OFF" and it all worked, populated the ID column automatically.  All good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifying a PK in your insert statement, you'll need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <tableName> ON` at the beginning of your query.

For more information, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql).

Comment: the SET IDENTITY_INSERT had nothing at all to do with a PK. It only works on identity fields. a PK does not have to be an identity field